# Airline caused missed international flight. What are my options?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, international-travel, compensation

I recently took an international flight booked through United from the US to the EU and back (with a connecting flight both ways) and on the way back they lost our ticket/reservation and we missed our original flights and arrived almost 12 hours later than originally scheduled.

I'm wondering what laws/regulations are in place to protect and compensate passengers who were caused to miss flights due to issues that are the fault of the airlines.

I've read up as much as I can on EU and US transportation rights but I'm having trouble finding explicit sections that support amounts of compensation and was hoping to get some help on people that might have more experience here.

I looked at the Involuntary Bumping section [here](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/fly-rights), which seems good, but the more references I have the better.

Comment: "Involuntary bumping" is only relevant if you're bumped because the flight is overbooked.  That's not what happened to you, so that section is not relevant here.  The US generally doesn't have many laws requiring passenger compensation and I don't think it mandates any compensation in your case.  The EU might be different.

Comment: It matters which airline, please edit and add.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I added the airline in the first paragraph. The flight was over booked and despite showing them our confirmed itinerary they said because it was they couldn't just put us on it at the check in counter, does that make a difference?

Comment: @KarolyS You say first that United "lost our ticket/reservation" (e.g. you tried to check in but they couldn't find your ticket at first) but then suggest the flight was overbooked (e.g. you did not previously secure a seat assignment, and then all seats were taken by the time you went to check in). These are different scenarios with potentially different remedies.

Comment: @choster You're correct, because it was on the way back their system didn't let me pick seats for those flights when I made the reservation which didn't seem out of the ordinary to me. I paid and got a confirmation email containing my full there and back itinerary with confirmation number and flight numbers. The main issue in my opinion is that they straight up lost my and my girlfriend's ticket/reservation. The fact our intended flight was overbooked is just an extra bit of information I thought might be relevant because they couldn't fix the problem by just putting us on our intended flight.

Comment: If "losing" a reservation has fewer consequences for the airline than involuntary bumping, this gives the airlines a potentially strong incentive to "accidentally lose" some reservations on overbooked flights.

Comment: Only reason I went with Involuntary Bumping is because that fit the situation the best. I haven't come across any laws/protections/regulations for straight up not having a record of a ticket that was purchased and confirmed and being turned away, but being disallowed from boarding despite having proof of purchase is relatively close to what happened and as I understand that's basically what Involuntarily Bumping is. I know comments aren't for discussion so if anyone has anything that can help in any case I would very much appreciate it, otherwise I'll keep looking.

Comment: As this is a flight departing from the EU, EU261 applies. They apparently owe you 600 euros (unless threre's more information than what you shared).

Comment: @KarolyS; What makes you so certain that they "straight up lost" your ticket rather than simply bumped you off due to overbooking? You keep asserting that is what happened, but you haven't described what you _actually personally observed_ to reach that conclusion (which in this age sounds rather extraordinary compared to a run-of-the-mill overbooking scenario).

Answer (score 1):

As your flight originated in the EU, the rules of [Flight Compensation Regulation 261/2004 (EU261)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004) apply.

If there are no other issues which may be your fault (arriving too late at the airport for instance), or extraordinary circumstances (a strike by ATC staff for instance), a delay of 12 hours means the airline owes you a compensation of €400 (if the distance was up to 3500 km) or €600 (above 3500 km).

Check the details of the regulation of exceptions and limitations.